# Passing variable from SAS to Python

Tags: python, sas

Is it possible to pass a macro variable from SAS to Python by using something like Command Line statements passed using the 'X' command? So far I have figured out a way of doing it that involves writing the macro variable to a text file, then having Python read that in.

That method seems like a possible banana skin in the code of having a critical step write out to a text file. I've looked through the forum an online for possible ways of doing it but not really found anything.

---

The code will dynamically generate the following string:

```
%let loader = "%NRSTR(finance.yahoo.com/d/... &svar11.+&svar12.+&svar13.+&svar14.+&svar15.+&svar16.+&svar17.+&svar18.+&svar19.‌​+&svar20.+ &svar21.+&svar22.+&svar23.+&svar24.+&svar25.+&svar26.+&svar27.+&svar28.+&svar29.‌​+&svar30.+ &svar31.+&svar32.+&svar33.+&svar34.+&svar35.+&svar36.+&svar37.+&svar38.+&svar39.‌​+&svar40.+ &svar41.+&svar42.+&svar43.+&svar44.+&svar45.+&svar46.+&svar47.+&svar48.+&svar49.‌​%NRSTR(&f=)&&fvar&a.";
```

Here the macro variables will resolve to stock ticker values provided for various exchanges earlier in the code. My original version of the code put this string in a filename url statement, but this was proving too slow so instead I have built something in Python that is a lot faster but is still hard coded. The Yahoo! stream this is going to will not support more than about 200 tickers at a time and the tickers being traded are updated daily so I cannot hard code them.

The rough idea would be to pass the macro variable &loader to command line via the X command, then have Python pick it up somehow. The text file method would be to write out the value of the resolved string above to a text file, then call some Python code from SAS (I'm ok on how to do that) which would create a variable at it's end from the text file. If it could all be done by passing a variable directly from SAS to Python via command line that would a lot cleaner i think.

Comment: Could you give some code/a specific example of what you want to happen?

Comment: The code will dynamically generate the following string:

    %let loader = "%NRSTR(http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=)&svar1.+&svar2.+&svar3.+&svar4.+&svar5.+&svar6.+&svar7.+&svar8.+&svar9.+&svar10.+
    &svar11.+&svar12.+&svar13.+&svar14.+&svar15.+&svar16.+&svar17.+&svar18.+&svar19.+&svar20.+ &svar21.+&svar22.+&svar23.+&svar24.+&svar25.+&svar26.+&svar27.+&svar28.+&svar29.+&svar30.+
    &svar31.+&svar32.+&svar33.+&svar34.+&svar35.+&svar36.+&svar37.+&svar38.+&svar39.+&svar40.+ &svar41.+&svar42.+&svar43.+&svar44.+&svar45.+&svar46.+&svar47.+&svar48.+&svar49.%NRSTR(&f=)&&fvar&a.";

Comment: Here the macro variables will resolve to stock ticker values provided for various exchanges earlier in the code. My original version of the code put this string in a filename url statement, but this was proving too slow so instead I have built something in Python that is a lot faster but is still hard coded.

The Yahoo! stream this is going to will not support more than about 200 tickers at a time and the tickers being traded are updated daily so I cannot hard code them.

The rough idea would be to pass the macro variable &loader to command line via the X command  , then have Python pick

Comment: it up somehow. The text file method would be to write out the value of the resolved string above to a text file, then call some Python code from SAS (I'm ok on how to do that) which would create a variable at it's end from the text file.

If it could all be done by passing a variable directly from SAS to Python via command line that would a lot cleaner i think.

Comment: Not completely sure I understand what your goal is but if you are trying to get stock quotes from Yahoo it would be easier to leave SAS out of the equation all together.  Python has a module ystockquote that may be of use.  You can find it here ... [link](https://github.com/cgoldberg/ystockquote)